# Formatting a cell based on the value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to setup a conditional formatting rule in a spreadsheet for an entire column. Basically it goes a little something like this

in any cell in column G, if the value in the cell on the same row in column A is 4 AND the cell in column G is blank then format it.
If the value in the corresponding cell in column A on the same row is NOT 4 then the cell in column G does not need formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple logical rule for this, you need to conditions to be `TRUE`, so you will use `AND`

Your two pieces of logic are:

`A1` must equal 4 AND `G1` must be blank. so compiled together you will use:

```
=AND(A1=4,G1="")
```

Select cell `G1`, and enter the above as the rule, then apply it the whole of column G.

Comment: how to "apply it the whole of column G"? It seems that rule could not be applied.