# How to format a cell based on another cell value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the Excel data as

[image]

I want to apply format to Column A when Column B is "okay":

[image]

I think I should use the formula to achieve this, but how to do them in one go?

[image]

It seems that [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1375612/formatting-a-cell-based-on-the-value-of-another-cell) could not apply the format rule to the entire column.

Comment: make sure the rule applies to the whole column `$A:$A` and use `=$B1="okay"`

Comment: I highlight the whole Column A, then add `=$B1="okay"`, but not work

Comment: when you open the conditional format rule manager, what does it say in the Applies to: box?

Comment: I see, I did not click the `Manage Rules", I only click the `New rules`. Now I can make it. Can you answer it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do the following:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select S1:S10.
- From HOME Tab hit Condition Formatting.
- Then New Rule, next is select Use a Formula to determine which cells to format.
- Use this =$T1="okay", as Format value where Formula is True.
- Hit Format button, apply an appropriate format and finish with Ok.

**Since you have already tried, so do this:**

- Select the data range, reach to conditional Formatting.
- Hit the Manage Command, you get this.

[image]

- Select and click Edit button, apply necessary changes as I've shown above, and finish with Ok.

**Note:** *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @lanselibai ,, please keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

1. Select Range you need- go to **Conditional Formatting**- **Manage Rules...**- **New rule**- **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**:
   [image]
2. Enter the formula: **=$B1="okay"**- select the fill color you need- click OK:
   [image]

Comment: Dear @Lee ,, your post is almost identical to mine,,, plzz check !!

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you have posted the answer when I added the answer. Sorry~